# Does there exist a continuous nonconstant function $f$ that maps almost all irrationals to rationals?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous nonconstant function on the reals. Could it map almost all irrationals to rationals?

This is impossible if $f$ maps *all* irrationals to rationals, by a well known result.

This is impossible if $f$ preserves measure 0 sets, because then $\{f(x)| f(x)\textrm{ is irrational}\}$ has measure $0$.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this well-known or trivial for some reason?

Comment: "This is impossible if f maps all irrationals to rationals, by a well known result." Can you give a reference to this?

Comment: @IosifPinelis: if it's nonconstant, its image contains an interval, and you don't have enough rationals to map to all the irrationals in that interval.

Comment: @NikWeaver : But the statement quoted in my comment was about mapping all irrationals to rationals, rather than vice versa.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: since $f$ is continuous and nonconstant its range contains an interval $[a,b]$. If all irrationals map to rationals then you don't have enough points left in the domain to hit all the irrationals in $[a,b]$.

Comment: @NikWeaver : Right, I had to think a bit more about this.

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220444/does-there-exist-a-continuous-function-f-bbb-r-to-bbb-r-that-is-rational-at

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) $c:[0,1] \to [0,1]$. It is rational almost everywhere. To create a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, apply a transform like $x \mapsto \frac {\sin x + 1} 2$, i.e., $f(x)=c(\frac {\sin x + 1} 2)$.

Comment: Or set $f(x+1)=f(x)+1$ for $x\notin[0,1]$.